# background image overlays the header unless it is position: fixed, but if fixed, it wont center

Tags: css, background, header, center, fixed

Due mostly to advice from this site (thanks) I created a fixed header with a simple nav and a partially transparent image.  I managed to put in a body background image (which I also want fixed, and no repeat) but the only way I could get it to NOT overlay the header was by making it css position:fixed.  My  problem, now, is that the background image wont center no matter how nicely I ask it to.

Is there a way to get the header container and the background image container to line up and both be centered?

Comment: Can you please include your styles here?

Comment: show use what you have done so far